# Javascript join(), i want to join some of them in array

Tags: javascript, join, split

in this case for example, i have array :

```
var myarr = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
```

**Question:** 
how to join "myarr", except "red" or one of them, or i want to join some of them (example).
for example, it becomes like below:
**greenblueyellow** 
thanks for advice..

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](http://jsfiddle.net/g47efgwc/)

```
var filterVal = 'green';
var joinedString = myarr.filter(function(item){
    return item !== filterVal;
}).join();

alert(joinedString);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g47efgwc/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

use the Array.filter method:

```
var myarr = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
var result = myarr.filter(function (item) {
    return item !== "red";
}).join("");
console.log('result', result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rpbL381g/

Answer (score 1):

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the element(s) you don't want:

```
myarr.filter(function(v) { return v !== 'red'; }).join('');
```

```js
var myarr = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
document.body.innerHTML = 
  myarr.filter(function(v) { return v !== 'red'; }).join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com)

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/kbuf097a/)

```
var result = jinqJs().from(myarr).where(function(row){return row !== 'green' && row !== 'blue'}).select();
```